# Line under chapter name at top of the page

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am writing a thesis, under the chapter name at the top of the page I would like a line to appear, but I don't have the palest idea on how to do that, I hope you can help.

**Edit:** I definitely wasn't clear enough. I meant this part of the page, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am using book.

Comment: Use the `fancyhdr` package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package to customize the headers/footers of your document; a little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduzione}
\lipsum[4]
\section{A Test Section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`E` stands for "even"; `O`, for "odd"; `L`, `C`, `R` stand for "left", "center", "right", respectively. So, for example, `\fancyhead[EL]{<text>}` will place `<text>` in the header to the left on even pages. By default, calling `\pagestyle{fancy}` draws a horizontal rule below the header.

I used `\nouppercase` since uppercased headers are not pleasing, but this is optional. The package documentation explains how you can further customize the marks used in the headers.